# Using LastRow in a Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have asked to find the last row in a Range with the following:

```
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Now, I'd like to select a range with a known column and an unknown last row. I'd like to fill in the entire column without overshooting the rows by insert an exact number. Here is what I have -

```
Range("AA2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaLocal = "=Vlookup(A2,[CP_QR_5_prep.xlsm]Sheet1!A2:LastRow,18,false)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AA2:AA & LastRow)
```

How can I correct my syntax and understand how to use lastrow/lastcolumn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pretty close.

The syntax you have for these lines:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaLocal = "=Vlookup(A2,[CP_QR_5_prep.xlsm]Sheet1!A2:LastRow,18,false)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AA2:AA & LastRow)
```

Should be:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaLocal = "=Vlookup(A2,[CP_QR_5_prep.xlsm]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$" & LastRow & ",18,false)" 'i added absolute referencing which I would think you need... if not take out the "$" signs
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AA2:AA" & LastRow)
```

Because, in order to read the variable value into your strings, you need to close the strings and concatenate the variable name.

I will also add that to get the actual last row of cells with data it's better to do something like this:

```
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

as using `UsedRange` could potentially leave you with an undesired answer if there are cells in the sheets with formatting or other cells that seem to be blank, but are not.

Comment: Thanks. Using lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ensures that even if a cell to the left of my column is blank lastrow will count all the way down?

Comment: Yes, sort of. It depends on your data set. Basically, pick a column upon which you want to find the *last real used cell* and substitute that column name in place of the `A` in the `Range("A" & Rows.Count)` portion of the syntax.